# Playframework form binding request illegalstate exception

Tags: playframework

I am getting this illegalStateException no value when trying to bind a form request. I think it has to do with my contact model has one to many mapping and I don't know how to handle that from bindfromquestion. Any example will help.

Thanks,
Tim

My Model is:

```
@Entity
public class Contact extends Model {

    @Id
    public long id;     
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName; 
    public String prefix;
    public String role;
    public String organization;
    public String website;
    public Date lastModDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact")
    public List<Address> address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact")
    public List<Email> email;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "contact")
    public List<PhoneNumber> phoneNumber;
```

}

Controller :

```
public static Result save(){
    Form<Contact> boundForm = contactForm.bindFromRequest();
    Contact contact = boundForm.get();
    contact.save();

    return ok(String.format("Saved contact %s", "contact"));

}
```